# want to get publish transaction id in deployer extension

Tags: sites-9.1, deployer-extension

I need to write a deployer extension where my requirement is to get the publish transaction id.

I tried with the following way:

```
public static String getTransactionId()
{
    ContentDeliveryKernel contentDeliveryKernel = null;
    try {
        contentDeliveryKernel = KernelFactory.getInstance().getKernel();
        TransactionManager tm = contentDeliveryKernel.getComponent(TransactionManager.class);
        Map<String, Long> activeTrans = tm.getActiveTransactions();
        if(activeTrans != null && !activeTrans.isEmpty())
        {
            Object keys[] = activeTrans.keySet().toArray();
            String rawTransId = (String)keys[0];
            return cleanupPackageId(rawTransId);
        }
    } catch (TridionLifecycleException ex) {
        return null;
    }

    return null;
}
```

But I am getting a stack overflow error after deployment on following line:
**contentDeliveryKernel = KernelFactory.getInstance().getKernel();**

If anybody knows a better way to get a published transaction id then it would be helpful.

I am using sites 9.1.

Comment: Following is the stack trace:

Comment: Is it a deployer extension or storage extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty easy. You have the following page for deployer extension sample:

https://docs.rws.com/783502/695281/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/creating-a-custom-module

Plus, the override methods in deployer extensions receive `TransportPackage` which has method `getTransactionId()`

```
    public void process(TransportPackage data) throws ProcessingException {
        try {
            ProcessorInstructions processorInstructions = data.getProcessorInstructions();
            TCMURI transactionID = data.getTransactionId();

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage());
        } finally {
            LOGGER.debug("**PageUndeployer process end**");
        }
    }
}
```